# save backup files to custom directory in Perl edit-in-place

Tags: windows, perl

I've a perl file **changes.pl** already. I can run *changes.pl* via **cmd command**. I'm looking for saving backup files to a specific directory. I've tried using **cmd command 1** and **2**. But, I get **result** from running any of both.

**changes.pl**

```
BEGIN {
    @ARGV = map glob("\"$_\""), @ARGV;
}

s/a/b/g;
s/c/d/g;
s/e/f/g;
```

**cmd command**

```
perl -i.bak -p changes.pl My/Files/Directory/*.txt
```

**cmd command 1**

```
perl -i"save/*" -p changes.pl My/Files/Directory/*.txt
```

**cmd command 2**

```
perl -i.bak -i"save/*" -p changes.pl My/Files/Directory/*.txt
```

**result**

> Can't do inplace edit on My/Files/Directory/File 1.txt: File exists.
>
> Can't do inplace edit on My/Files/Directory/File 2.txt: File exists.
>
> Can't do inplace edit on My/Files/Directory/File 3.txt: File exists.

**Note:**

- I'm using Perl on Windows.
- I've gotten **changes.pl** and **cmd command** from Borodin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31774619/4123648) on a previous question of mine.

Comment: @ikegami How could I do this?

Comment: `perldoc open` is the place to start.

Comment: @Sobrique I've found these guides [1](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) & [2](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) about `perldoc open`. But I unfortunately can't get how this would be beneficial for this case.

Comment: Is the result `"Can't do inplace edit on My/Files/Directory/File 1.txt: File exists."` from running command 1 or command 2?

Comment: @HåkonHægland from running any of both.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steverowe/archive/2008/11/26/using-perl-for-mass-in-place-editing.aspx

tl;dr; Try using a for loop instead of a wildcard. And don't forget quotes around "%i" as you do have spaces in your filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Just repeating Druxa's answer with [an archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150715221221/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steverowe/archive/2008/11/26/using-perl-for-mass-in-place-editing.aspx) since the original is down and paraphrasing below in case that goes down too.

To use perl to replace every instance of M1 with M2, the command for this is -e (execute?). To change something inline, you can use the -i (in place) command. The command looks something like this:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/M1/M2/g" file.txt
```

The -i.bak means to rename the original files with the .bak extention. In theory -i alone will delete the originals but ActivePerl wouldn't accept this.

The -p tells perl to run the command over every line of standard input (i.e. over every line of the file).

The "s/M1/M2/g" command is a regular expression telling it to substitute M2 for M1 globally. It could be any regular expression. Hint: If the command fails, try adding -w to the command line to generate warnings.
On Windows, the MSDN blog post author warns that quoting with single quotes (') wont work, so you should use double quotes (")
In *nix using a shell interpteter like bash, [it interprets some special characters differently using double quotes (")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) so you should use single quotes (')

The above command will change all instances of M1 to M2 in file.txt. What I wanted to do was to replace it in every file. Simple, I'll just change file.txt to *.*. Sorry, no dice. ActivePerl doesn't accept this nor does it accept *. Time for some more command-line action. There is a for command that can be utilized at the cmd prompt which fits the bill. Use it like so:

```
for %i in (*.txt) do perl -pi.bak -e "s/M1/M2/g" "%i"
```

This command will iterate over all the files (*.txt) and execute the command following the do. **You have to quote the trailing %i because filenames might contain spaces.** Note that perl regular expressions are capable of much more than simple search and replace. You can use this technique to accomplish anything they can.