# perl on Windows: Can't do inplace edit on file: File exists

Tags: windows, perl

I've alread read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2616865/7050476) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32469663/7050476) question, which led me to:

```
for f in *.Xml
do
  perl -pi.bak -e 's/\x03//g' "$f"
done
rm *.bak
```

I am using a for loop and I'm using `-pi.bak`. I still get `Can't do inplace edit on 20180619.Xml: File exists.`. I also tried this from Windows' `cmd.exe` instead of from git bash:

```
for %i in (*.Xml) do perl -pi.bak -e "s/\x03//g" "%i"
```

Same thing. Any ideas?

Version info:

```
$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for x86_64-msys-thread-multi
```

I am using the latest version of Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the file was open (for reading) by another process.

```
$ handle 20180619.Xml

Nthandle v4.11 - Handle viewer
Copyright (C) 1997-2017 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Rgui.exe           pid: 11520  type: File           488: C:\20180619.Xml
Rgui.exe           pid: 11520  type: File           530: C:\20180619.Xml
Rgui.exe           pid: 11520  type: File           680: C:\20180619.Xml
```

Killing the process solves the issue.