# How to replace multiple any-character (including newline) in Perl RegEx?

Tags: regex, windows, perl, cmd

This is a simplified description of [MyTextString.txt](http://pastebin.com/yfDvZTyi):

*Note: **BlaBla** stands for any character including new line character.*

> **START** BlaBla-In **END** BlaBla-Out-Between **START** BlaBla-In **END** BlaBla-Out-Between **START** BlaBla-In **END** BlaBla-Out-Between **START** BlaBla-In **END** ...

I'm looking for removing *text between END and START (BlaBla-Out-Between)* to result like this:

> **START** BlaBla-In **END** newline **START** BlaBla-In **END** newline **START** BlaBla-In **END** newline **START** BlaBla-In **END** ...

I've a perl file **changes.pl**:

```
BEGIN {
    @ARGV = map glob("\"$_\""), @ARGV;
}

s/(END).*?(START)/$1\n$2/sg; #TEST
```

I should execute my replaces using this **CMD line**:

```
perl -i.bak -p changes.pl My/File/Directory/MyTextString.txt
```

Note: the *changes.pl* and *CMD line* are working well as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774499/apply-multiple-find-and-replace-regex-queries-on-multiple-txt-files-using-a-per) with other RegEx find and replace strings.

But with this RegEx string no modifications happen to MyTextString.txt:

```
s/(END).*?(START)/$1\n$2/sg;
```

I think every thing regarding my regular expression syntax is OK as it's working well on [regex 101 tester](https://regex101.com/r/pH8kM4/2).

I'm looking for matching and replacing **any character (including newline)** using mentioned *changes.pl* and *CMD line*. Simply, I'm looking for replacing *BlaBla-Out-Between* with *newline*.

Comment: You need to slurp the whole file into a string before doing the substitution. The `-p` command line switch only reads a line at a time

Comment: @HåkonHægland Exactly.. It is required to read the entire file in a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slurp the whole file into a string before doing the substitution. The `-p` command line switch only reads a line at a time.

It means that  the substitution `s/(END).*?(START)/$1\n$2/sg` will only delete anything in those cases where there is an `END` pattern followed by a `START` pattern on the same single line.

To slurp the file you can specify an input record separator of octal `0777`:

```
perl -0777 -p -i.bak changes.pl MyTextString.txt
```

From [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> **-0[octal/hexadecimal]**
>
> specifies the input record separator ($/ ) as an octal or hexadecimal number. If there are no digits, the null
>   character is the separator. Other switches may precede or follow the
>   digits. ... The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode. Any value 0400 or
>   above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by convention the
>   value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose.