# Perl command line to replace text block across multi-line using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I've got a bunch of html files that I need to replace the following text:

```
<div id="header">
plus all info between
<!-- end #header -->
```

with

```
<?php include ("header.php"); ?>
```

I thought I could run something like this but it isn't matching the text:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/<div id="header">.*<!\-\- end #header \-\->/<\?php include \("header\.php"\); \?>/g' *.html
```

or

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/<div id="header">[\S\s\n]*<!\-\- end \#header \-\->/<\?php include \("header\.php"\); \?>/img' *.html
```

I don't know if it's not searching across multiple lines and I need a parameter or I'm not escaping characters right.  Any help would be appreciated.

I would like to batch run this in a directory and change all the content within each file where appropriate.

EDIT: looking for a single command line version, not using multiple pl files if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to replace multiple any-character (including newline) in Perl RegEx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533282/how-to-replace-multiple-any-character-including-newline-in-perl-regex/36534283#36534283)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but that explains why it's not working (-p option is the culprit?) but I don't understand what the structure should be of the search-and-replace code in the example.  It would be helpful if we could have an actual working copy of the example above.

Comment: Is there perhaps an alternative to the -p command to read the file as one line?  And how would the SnR code be integrated?   Ideally I'm thinking this can be coded as a single command line without having to create a separate perl file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the record separator with the `-0` option. Like so:

```
perl -0pe 's/.../.../g' *.html
```

This sets the record separator to the `NUL` character, so that the entire file is read at once, rather than line by line.

Comment: This should work, but one day a file will  come along that contains a legitimate NUL character and your command will break. It's best to use `perl -0777 -pe ' ... '` which sets `$/` to `undef`