# Perl replace match+nextline+match

Tags: regex, perl, sed, str-replace

I have lines in file:

```
Desktop DELL firewall UP CPU 20core configured 
Desktop HP firewall DOWN CPU 18core unconfigured
```

I want to first match `UP` and then if next line match `DOWN` replace these two lines with some string

I tried

```
perl -p -e 's?.*firewall.*UP.*\n.*firewall.*DOWN.*?STRG?' file
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to replace multiple any-character (including newline) in Perl RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36533282/2173773)

Answer (score 2):

`/\n.*f/` can't possibly match since you are reading newline-terminated lines one at a time.

A convenient trick is to use `-0777` to load the entire file into memory at once.

```
perl -0777pe's/^.*firewall.*UP.*\n.*firewall.*DOWN.*/STRG/m' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed '/firewall.*UP/{N;/firewall[^\n]*DOWN/s/.*/somestr/}' file
```

details:

```
/firewall.*UP/ {      # condition
    N;                # append the next line to the pattern space
    /firewall[^\n]*DOWN/  # condition
        s/.*/somestr/ # then: replace all with somestr
}
```

Comment: Might this create a false positive if `DOWN` was in the same line as `UP`?

Comment: @potong: clearly yes, but I doubt this can happen. However I will replace the second `.*` with `[^\n]*` to be sure that *firewall* and *DOWN* are on the same line (the second one).